# Tried to install web3 on Python vscode several times but this error popped up

Tags: python, web3py

```
  Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Please start at the beginning, by describing what you did and what output (text, not images) you got in response. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: The file you are trying to install does not contain a Windows binary. So `pip` is trying to compile it from source. But it appears your computer does not have a suitable C compiler, as this message explains: *Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/*. So your first step is to follow that advice. Even after you do, be aware that compiling from source on Windows can be less than straightforward.

Comment: You'll find this _much_ easier if you install VirtualBox (it's free) and install Ubuntu in a virtual machine (that's free as well). Then you can do the same task in an operating system where compilation is easy and commonplace.

Comment: Thank you so much i fixed it by installing C++ 14.0. Super Helpful!